python is giving zsh: bus error while attempting create image embeddings
I'm trying to use an ML model to create image embeddings. This code block will send embeddings to ES cluster, but it gives an error;
zsh: bus error
I don't know why, i'm not good at python
It's my current python code;
from transformers import CLIPProcessor, CLIPModel
import torch
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch


es = Elasticsearch("my-es-cluster", basic_auth=('elastic', 'password'))


model_id = 'patrickjohncyh/fashion-clip'
model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained(model_id)
processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained(model_id)

def preprocess_image(image_path):
   
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    return image

def get_image_embedding(image_path):
   
    image = preprocess_image(image_path)
    
    inputs = processor(images=image, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
    
    with torch.no_grad():  
        embedding = model.get_image_features(**inputs)
    
    return embedding

def index_image_embedding(image_id, embedding):
 
    doc = {
        'image_id': image_id,
        'embedding': embedding.squeeze().tolist()  
    }
    es.index(index="images", document=doc)

def process_all_images(image_folder):
  
    for image_name in os.listdir(image_folder):
        if image_name.endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png')):  
            image_path = os.path.join(image_folder, image_name)
           
            embedding = get_image_embedding(image_path)
            
            image_id = os.path.splitext(image_name)[0]  
           
            index_image_embedding(image_id, embedding)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    image_folder = '/Users/sevbantumer/Desktop/images_less/' 
   
    process_all_images(image_folder)

what kind of change must be made?
Please give me a hand, i'm completely confused
note: M1 macOS sequoia
thanks in advance

hi, this lacks detail. show all your workings/errors (copy/paste only pls), how this script in invoked etc. suggest you read 'https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example' . are all those packages compatible with ARM h/ware ?, do you have any other scripts running zsh that work fine ?
